# How can I make my divs slide horizontally using keyframes?

Tags: css

I'm trying to get my divs to slide horizontally when on hover, but currently they dont stay at the same rotation when on hover, I'm looking at translate() but how do you say move down in current rotation ?

```
.box
    width: 200px
    height: 400px
    float: left
    border: solid black 1px
    transform: rotateZ(25deg)
    margin-top: -100px
    &:hover
        transform: translateX(-10px)    translateY(100px)
```

see codepen
http://codepen.io/MrJoshFisher/pen/yJRPWP

the idea is as follows 
[image]

so when you hover on one of the box it slides up then when your mouse leaves it goes back down

Comment: Please fix your pen, it has an error in sass: Inconsistent indentation: 4 spaces were used for indentation, but the rest of the document was indented using 1 tab.

Comment: Fixed it see again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add `rotate` to your animation `transform` as well:

```
@keyframes shine 
    0% 
        transform: translateX(0px) translateY(0px) rotateZ(25deg)
    100%
        transform: translateX(-80px) translateY(100px) rotateZ(25deg)
```

Comment: cheers helped a lot, and sorry is it translationY(-100) to make it go up rather than down ?

Comment: `translationY(-100px)` will move it up, but not diagonal, you will need to change `translateX` to positive value (say `80px`?)